# Type does not contain definition of 'Round' and 'Parse'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, compiler-errors

I get this strange error and it doesn't compile. My code looks like this:

```
 if (model.CreditType == "Extra")
    {
    decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(amountReturn.ToString()) / model.CreditPeriod;
   ((dynamic)base.ViewBag).MonthlyPayment = Math.Round(num1, 2, 
   MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
   dynamic viewBag = base.ViewBag;
   Type type = typeof(Math);
   decimal num2 = num1;
   Type type1 = typeof(decimal);
   viewBag.MonthlyPaymentWithTax = type.Round(num2 + 
   type1.Parse(((dynamic)base.ViewBag).TaxToAdd.ToString()) / 
   model.CreditPeriod, 2, 1);
   }
```

I will be very thankful if somebody explains me how to fix my problem. On compile it generates the following errors.

Thank you in advance!

[image: compilation errors]

Comment: Why you're using `Type` if `Math.Round()` and `decimal.Parse()` just enough? Of course `System.Type` doesn't have both `Round()` and `Parse()` methods, they're exist in respective class/struct.

Comment: You're doing some very strange things in that code, OP. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? You shouldn't have to do all that casting or use `dynamic` just to do math.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error, the Type doesn't contain a definition for both Round and Parse. You need to use Decimal.Parse and Decimal.Round instead

You need to use

```
   viewBag.MonthlyPaymentWithTax = Decimal.Round(num2 + 
   Decimal.Parse(((dynamic)base.ViewBag).TaxToAdd.ToString()) / 
   model.CreditPeriod, 2);
```

You can read more on both methods here

[Decimal.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[Decimal.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @InvanteCaprito What is the third parameter in your Round method call. What do you intend it to be ? The parameter for Decimal.Round is a) value to be rounded, b) number of decimal places. The third parameter is  actually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know asp.net but I think I could explain about your error.

When you use `typeof(myobj)` this expression returns an instance of `System.Type`, not a same of referencing type itself in code, like `Int.Parse()`.

An instance of `System.Type` is representation of runtime type information. It's a kind of "meta" object, not same as referencing the type you want on code.

It you wish to call a specific method via `System.Type` object, you should find it first. This method of calling is called as "Reflection". I recommend you to not do this because it is not easy, needs boilerplate(?) and not needed in most time when you know your type. [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2)

I just recommend first cast your target type and just call the static method of type (like the other answer did). or use TryParse?

(code is not tested for compilation)

```cs
dynamic a = "123";
string a_casted = 123 as string;
if (a_casted == null) { return; }

int a_parsed = Int.Parse(a_casted);
```